# Count of majority value for each cell?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, spatial-statistics, statistics, cell-statistics

I ran 10 classifications (*Random Trees*) in ArcMap. Each time the output will be somewhat different.
I have made a final map based on the majority value of each pixel using *cell statistics (majority)*. 
I have also produced a map where the number of different class values is reported using *cell statistics (variety).*

Now I want a map that reports the count of the majority value. E.g. the majority value was 2, how many times out of the 10 did value 2 occur for each pixel.

I know how I could do this using several steps, but as I am running the iteration of 10 classification on 8 different areas this would be extremely time consuming.

Is there a tool or a simple way to estimate or count the number of times the majority value was reported for each cell?

Comment: Equal To Frequency tool will do it. http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/equal-to-frequency.htm

Comment: Thank you @FelixIP, it worked like a charm!

Comment: Nice one @FelixIP!